# How to save SMTPDebug = 3 in log file through error_log function

Tags: php, phpmailer

I want to save SMTPDebug = 3, mail error into log file.
below code used in php file, but blank show in log file.
please suggest, how to store SMTP debug information in log file.

```
if(!$mail->send()) 
     {                   
       error_log($mail->SMTPDebug = 3, 3, "smtp_connection_error.log");
                     
                    
     } 
        else
         {
             //echo 'The email message was sent.';
            return true;

            }
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your `error_log()` function contains, so I can't help you there.  However, the first argument you're passing appears to be trying to set a value on `$mail->SMTPDebug` - did you mean to do this?  What should the first argument to your function be?

Comment: @RobEyre won't it be the built-in PHP [error_log function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php)?

Comment: @ADyson - ah, correct, my mistake.  Thanks.  However, my comment about the first argument still stands.  The first argument to `error_log()` should be a string, but the code is passing the value `3`

Answer (score 0):

As per https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/SMTP-Debugging#debug-output-format you can configure PHPMailer to output directly to your PHP error log file:

```
$mail->Debugoutput = "error_log";
```

Quote from the above documentation:

> The form that the debug output takes is determined by the Debugoutput property. This has several options:
>
> `echo` Output plain-text as-is, appropriate for CLI
>
> `html` Output escaped, line breaks converted to `<br>`, appropriate for browser output
>
> `error_log` Output to error log as configured in php.ini

Comment: Thanks for Response

phpmailer already configured
As your suggestion, below code edited but error_log file not created and not write in commented line.
 

    if(!$mail->send()) 
     {
    
      $level = 3;
      $str ="ok";
      $mail->Debugoutput = function($str, $level) {echo "debug level $level; message: $str";};
      $mail->Debugoutput = "error_log";
         //error_log($mail->Debugoutput, 3, "smtp_connection_error.log");
      
      }

Comment: @MayankSudden `but error_log file not created`...well did you also configure PHP to log errors to the error log file in php.ini? If not then it won't work

Comment: Thanks for Response..... When use this error_log($mail->ErrorInfo, 3, "smtp_connection_error.log"); then log file created and errorinfo written in smtp_connection_error.log file but error info very less, so want to save SMTPdebug. for more info. please suggest with code, if it is possible.

Comment: There is no more code to suggest. You didn't answer my question - did you also configure PHP error logging in `php.ini`?

Comment: error_log = php_errors.log done in php.ini

Comment: Ok. So then if you have `$mail->Debugoutput = "error_log";` you should expect to see the debug output added in `php_errors.log` when you run the code.

Comment: If that still doesn't work for some reason, then you can try using a custom function like this example: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/issues/911#issuecomment-268766626